# how can i enter the elements of the array and every time we get the new element,we put it in the middle of array?

Tags: c++

the thing is that i know how to put an element in the specific position of existing array,but i dont know how to get the elements that i want by user and put elements id the middle.

```
int arr[100] = { 0 }; 
int i, x, pos, n = 10; 

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    arr[i] = i + 1; 


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
printf("\n"); 


x = 50;
pos = 5; 
n++; 


for (i = n; i >= pos; i--) 
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1]; 


arr[pos - 1] = x; 


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Your loop looks ok, for (i = n; i >= pos; i--) arr[i] = arr[i - 1]; arr[pos] = x is ok.
But.. I have questions: I agree with Thomas your problem is not clear. What do you mean by "by user" ? and "middle" ? maybe it is more clear if you explain the purpose of the shift. When you want to keep all elements in the right sorting order, while inserting new values, go through your list, locate the first (arr[i]>x) and then, use your loop to put the new number in the right position. If you do that every time, elements will remain in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a std::list

```
std::list<int> arr;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    arr.push_back(i + 1); 

for (const auto &el : arr) 
    printf("%d ", el); 
printf("\n"); 

const int x = 50;
const std::size_t pos = 5; 

arr.insert(pos - 1, x); 
arr.pop_back();

for (const auto &el : arr) 
    printf("%d ", el); 
printf("\n");
```